# What's wrong with the result of android.opengl.Matrix.rotateM?

Tags: android, opengl-es

My code:

```
            float[] rotatePlus90Mtx = identityMatrix.clone();
            Matrix.setRotateM(rotatePlus90Mtx, 0, 90, 0, 0, 1);
            Log.e(TAG, "RotatePlus90 Matrix: ");
            dumpMatrix(rotatePlus90Mtx);
```

the result:

`-4.371139E-8       1.0     0.0     0.0`
`-1.0       -4.371139E-8        0.0     0.0`

0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0

0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0

why there is -4.371139E-8? should be 0 correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It pretty much is zero; floating point numbers are not precise ...

Worth a read:

- "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point
  Arithmetic"
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html